# Ignore paragraphs in text-flow in OpenOffice

Tags: openoffice, layout

My goal is to place short summaries of a paragraph next to the paragraph (like, e.g., here: http://www.media-perspektiven.de/uploads/tx_mppublications/06-2013_Moebus_Heffler.pdf) - using OpenOffice.

And (that is the harder part) I do not want to use text boxes to do so. The reason is that my text will be 150+ pages and placing hundrets of text boxes will make managment very hard.

**What I did so far**

I creates a paragraph template "summary" with a lot of padding left and a negative padding right. That will place the paragraph on the right border, outside of the text area. Perfect so far.

I also added this paragraph template to the chapter structure (header 8 or so), so I will see the summaries in my navigator if I like so. Makes it much easier to track the structure :)

My problem is: These paragraphs have some heigth. That shifts the subsequent text down. Is there any solution to ignore a paragraph'l height for text-flow layout in OpenOffice?

Thanks for any suggestions.